# VB.NET Active Reports

Tags: vb.net, activereports

I have a VB active report which has many different attributes. The report contains attributes area, balance, id and status and is currently grouped my area. What I need to do now is remove all lines from the report where the balance is equal to 0 and the status equal to deactive. The information for the active report is from my database. Thus I think the best way would be to only select records where the balance is not 0 and status not equal to deactive. Is there a way I can query my database and have the active report be based off the query results? Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You asked "Is there a way I can query my database and have the active report be based off the query results?"...that is the standard way you write a report, you'd have to work harder to not get the data from the DB.  Can you please edit your question to include details of where you get your data from now if it is not a DB data source with a select statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the best way to do this is to change the query so that only the minimum records you need are actually coming into the report. [The Modify Data Sources at Run Time topic](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports6_start.html?topic67.html) from the documentation shows how to modify that SQL statement in the code dynamically at runtime.

If you can hard-code the SQL query for the report you should probably just modify the SQL at design time inside the designer. [This Bind Reports to a Data Source topic](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports6_start.html?topic34.html) shows you how to do that.

You can also programatically control the visibility of fields/textboxes based on the data using the Format event of the section containing those controls (most likely `Detail_Format`), but it sounds to me like modifying the SQL query is your best bet.